# Difference between two matrix columns appears two times (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created a new measure with the difference between two categories of data; but when I put it in a matrix, this information appears two times.

I have a database with this format:

```
Type    Month   Item    Value
real    1   earnings    10
real    2   earnings    15
real    3   earnings    20
real    4   earnings    10
real    5   earnings    11
ppto    1   earnings    10
ppto    2   earnings    12
ppto    3   earnings    13
ppto    4   earnings    12
ppto    5   earnings    10
```

then I created a Measure like this:

```
Difference =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( BASE[Value] ); BASE[Type] = "real" )
    - CALCULATE ( SUM ( BASE[Value] ); BASE[Type] = "ppto" )
```

the problem is when I put the new variable in a Matrix, I obtain this (repeated two columns of differences):

[image: Matrix data]

[image: Table 1]

but I would like the result in one column. Like this:

[image: Table 2]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have `Tipo` in the `Columns` field and that has multiple values.

One possible solution is to remove `Tipo` from the columns and use three measures.

```
real = CALCULATE ( SUM ( BASE[Value] ); BASE[Type] = "real" )
ppto = CALCULATE ( SUM ( BASE[Value] ); BASE[Type] = "ppto" )
Difference = [real] - [ppto]
```